# XSL-FO error with block-container during generation PDF

Tags: .net, apache, xslt, apache-fop

I have problem when I try to generate PDF with a file XSL-FO. 
My XSL :

`

```
fo:block-container position="absolute" absolute-position="absolute" top="49mm" left="24mm" width="165mm" height="30mm" >
<fo:block>
      <fo:table>
                <fo:table-column column-width="79mm"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="80mm"/>`

                <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row height="10mm">
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="box" number-rows-spanned="2">                            
                            <fo:block>

                <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">bold</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="text-align">center</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Interface/dossier_num"/> <xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Dossier/no_dossier"/>
              </fo:block>
                            <fo:block>
                                <fo:table>
                                    <fo:table-column />                                 
                                    <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row>
                                            <fo:table-cell>
                                                <fo:block font-size="8pt">
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="text-align">left</xsl:attribute>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Interface/code_produit"/><xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Table/code_produit"/>
                                                </fo:block>
                                            </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                                        <fo:table-row>
                                            <fo:table-cell>
                                                <fo:block font-size="8pt">
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="text-align">left</xsl:attribute>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Interface/modele"/><xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Table/modele"/>
                                                </fo:block>
                                            </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row>
                                            <fo:table-cell>
                                                <fo:block font-size="8pt">
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="text-align">left</xsl:attribute>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Interface/provenance"/><xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Table/mag_depot"/>
                                                </fo:block>                                             
                                            </fo:table-cell>
                                        </fo:table-row>
                                        <fo:table-row>
                                            <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block font-size="8pt">
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="text-align">left</xsl:attribute>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Interface/numero_serie"/><xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Table/serie"/>
                                                </fo:block>
                                            </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row>
                                            <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block font-size="8pt">
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="text-align">left</xsl:attribute>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Interface/garantie"/><xsl:text>: </xsl:text>                         
                          <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="/NewDataSet/Table/sous_garantie='true'"><xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Interface/oui"/></xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Interface/non"/></xsl:otherwise>
                          </xsl:choose>                                             
                                                </fo:block>                                             
                                            </fo:table-cell>
                                        </fo:table-row>
                                        <fo:table-row>
                                            <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block font-size="8pt">
                                                    <xsl:attribute name="text-align">left</xsl:attribute>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Interface/marque"/><xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Table/marque"/>
                                                </fo:block>
                                            </fo:table-cell>                                            
                                        </fo:table-row>
                                        <fo:table-row>                                          
                                            <fo:table-cell>
                                                <fo:block font-weight="bold" text-align="right">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Table/nom"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Table/prenom"/>
                                                </fo:block>                                             
                                            </fo:table-cell>
                                        </fo:table-row>
                                    </fo:table-body>
                                </fo:table>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>        
            <fo:table-cell>
              <fo:table>
                <fo:table-column column-width="40mm"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="40mm"/>

                <fo:table-body>
                  <fo:table-row height="14mm">
                    <fo:table-cell display-align="center">
                      <fo:block  font-weight="bold" text-align="center">

                        <xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Dossier/no_dossier"/>

                      </fo:block>
                      <fo:block  font-weight="bold" text-align="center">
                        <xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Table/code_produit"></xsl:value-of>
                      </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell display-align="center">
                      <fo:block  font-weight="bold" text-align="center">
                        <xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Dossier/no_dossier"/>

                      </fo:block>
                      <fo:block  font-weight="bold" text-align="center">
                        <xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Table/code_produit"></xsl:value-of>
                      </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                  </fo:table-row >
                  <fo:table-row height="14mm">                                  
                  <fo:table-cell display-align="center">
                    <fo:block  font-weight="bold" text-align="center">
                      <xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Dossier/no_dossier"/>

                    </fo:block>
                    <fo:block  font-weight="bold" text-align="center">
                      <xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Table/code_produit"></xsl:value-of>
                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell display-align="center">
                    <fo:block  font-weight="bold" text-align="center">
                      <xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Dossier/no_dossier"/>
                    </fo:block>
                    <fo:block  font-weight="bold" text-align="center">
                      <xsl:value-of select="NewDataSet/Table/code_produit"></xsl:value-of>
                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
              </fo:table-row>
              </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
            </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>  
`</fo:block>
</fo:block-container>
```

`

I have this error :
Impossible cast object of type 'org.apache.fop.layout.BlockArea' on type 'org.apache.fop.layout.AreaContainer

When I try to generate in an other project which use the same dll (apachefop.net) I have no error.
How can I replace this node ? How can I solve this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have fo:table as a child to fo:table-cell. Wrap that table in a block.

Comment: Hello, no i can delete all the content in fo:block-container, I have the same problem. However the problem disappear when i delete the block-container.